# How to split string values across a list of dictionaries, so that each part of the split string is in it's own dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How to split string values across a list of dictionaries, so that each part of the split string is in it's own dictionary?

For example:

```
lst = [{item:'321,121,343','name':'abby','amount':'400'},{item:'111,222,333','name':'chris','amount':'500'}]
```

I'd like each part of the item key-value pair to be in its own dictionary

```
Desired_List = [{item:'321','name':'abby','amount':'400'},{item:'121','name':'abby','amount':'400'},{item:'343','name':'abby','amount':'400'},{item:'111','name':'chris','amount':'500'},{item:'222','name':'chris','amount':'500'},{item:'333','name':'chris','amount':'500'}]
```

I've tried this with no luck:

```
[li.update({li['item']:spl}) for li in lst for spl in li['item'].split(',')]
return Li
```

Comment: Is the example intended to be `lst = [{item:'321,121,343','name':'abby','amount':'400'},{item:'111,222,333','name':'chris','amount':'500'}]`?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use a dict in which the key : value is '321' : dict? That is, each item value is a key in which the value is a dict?

Comment: Eli Rose, you were right. Human, I see what you mean, but that's not the dict I have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def unpack_dict(d, field, unpack):
    packed = d.pop(field)
    for item in unpack(packed):
        result = d.copy()
        result[field] = item
        yield result

lst = [
    {'item':'321,121,343','name':'abby','amount':'400'},
    {'item':'111,222,333','name':'chris','amount':'500'}
]

new_lst = [
    ud
    for d in lst
    for ud in unpack_dict(d, "item", lambda item: item.split(","))
]
```

gives `new_lst` =

```
[
    {'amount': '400', 'item': '321', 'name': 'abby'},
    {'amount': '400', 'item': '121', 'name': 'abby'},
    {'amount': '400', 'item': '343', 'name': 'abby'},
    {'amount': '500', 'item': '111', 'name': 'chris'},
    {'amount': '500', 'item': '222', 'name': 'chris'},
    {'amount': '500', 'item': '333', 'name': 'chris'}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working script:

```
lst = [{'item':'321,121,343','name':'abby','amount':'400'}, {'item':'321,121,343','name':'chris','amount':'500'}]

new_list = [{'item':j, 'name': i['name'], 'amount': i['amount']} for i in lst for j in i['item'].split(',')]

>>> print new_list
[{item:'321','name':'abby','amount':'400'},{item:'121','name':'abby','amount':'400'},{item:'343','name':'abby','amount':'400'},{item:'111','name':'chris','amount':'500'},{item:'222','name':'chris','amount':'500'},{item:'333','name':'chris','amount':'500'}]
```

Demo: http://repl.it/RaE

Comment: The only issue is that my actual list of Dictionaries has many more key-value pairs than this, so it's annoying and time-consuming to write each key out. I wonder if there is a way around this aspect, so I wouldn't have to write out the 'name' key-value pair or the 'amount' key-value pair for example.